# How can I observe the style on an element during mouse-over?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, debugging, firebug

We supply micro-site content to a client. They supply us with a HTML wrapper and we inject our content into it. I'm trying to debug an issue where our style sheet appears to be interfering with the style in their wrapper.

Normally I'd use firebug or IE Developer Toolbar to select the element and I can see which styles are being applied, which are being overridden and where they are coming from. But this particular problem only exists when I hover the mouse over a link. Specifically, the link shrinks a little bit.

Is there anything that I can use to see what the browser is doing with the styles when I hover the mouse over the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the element. Select 'inspect element'. In the firebug html window click on the tag you're interested in. Hover over the element in page. You should see the style change to e.g a:hover